# RSA Encryption problem, C, e and N are given

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption

I have the follwing task: the public key(e,N) = (5,299) and the encrypted message C = 60
Now I have to find the original message without knowing the private key d. So I come up with the following equation according to how C is calculated:

60 = M^5 mod 299, where M < n.

But I have no idea how to continue, trying each number from 0 until 298 isn't really a good method. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the original assignment/homework text to your question. There is some information missing which would make this task reasonable.

Comment: one tip from my task is that maybe extended euclidean algorithm helps, otherwise that's all information I can extract from the question. I think this task is solvable because N is small enough so even if we lose the private key there could be still a way to get there.

Comment: Can you add the original assignment/homework text to your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can factorize 299 into 13 and 23, so you have `p` and `q`. And from there you can calculate `phi(n)`, which is 12*22=264. Now you need to calculate the inverse of `e`, or solve the expression `e * d = 1 mod 264`. As 264 is 265-1 and `e` is 5 you can simply get to 265 by calculating 5*53. This will be your `d`. And now you have everything you need, as you can calculate 60^53 mod 299, which is 21, the original message `M`.

To verify the solution, calculate 21^5, which is 4084101. That mod 299 is 60, your original encrypted message `C`.